# jar eclipse launch configuration - what does it mean and how do i use it in my example?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects P1 and P2. P2 depends on P1 and both have their own main. I am trying to convert both into JARS.

When I try to make P1 into a JAR, i see a dialog box with "launch configuration" field in it. 
I don't know what this does. I entered P1 into it and the jar was ready. Did I get this correctly ?

I also want to make a jar out of P2. What do i enter in the launch config for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Launch configuration**: Select a 'Java Application' launch configuration to use to create a runnable JAR.

If you have already "**Run**" or **Set the run configuration of** this project in Eclipse, you can find the according launch configuration in this drop down list of **Launch configuration**.

[image]

Thus, what you need to do is to speificy the correct configuration for the correct jar. The one starts with P1 main method for P1, the other starts with P2 main method for P2.

Comment: yes, i could make a jar. But, now I need to know how to run that jar. I made a runnable jar, but cannot run it. How do i do that ?

Comment: @AppleGrinder Normally you can launch by double-clicking (JRE installed of course), otherwise, try **javaw -jar project.jar** in command line.

Comment: Double clicked, nothing happens. How to run jar from eclipse ?